# SQL Server - Gaps and Islands

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table with Start date and End Date,
For Example,

PlaceID |  StartDate |    EndDate

1     |   2020-01-01   | 2020-01-04
2     |   2020-01-03   | 2020-01-06
1     |   2020-01-10   | 2020-01-15
2     |   2020-01-20   | 2020-01-23

I need to write a script to get the Date ranges that is not in the table for each PlaceID.(For now considering January Month)
For PlaceID 1 - I need the output date Ranges as - 2020-01-05 to 2020-01-09 and 2020-01-16 to 2020-01-31
For PlaceID 2 - I need the output date Ranges as - 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-02, 2020-01-07 to 2020-01-19 and
2020-01-24 to 2020-01-31

What is the sql logic behind this that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script which gives the result for one of the PlaceID, What if I wanted to get the values for both/all the placeIDs available

```
DECLARE @t table(PlaceID int, StartDate date, EndDate date);
INSERT @t(PlaceID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
(1,'20200101','20200104'),(1,'20200110','20200115'),
(2,'20200103','20200106'),(2,'20200120','20200123');


-- input parameters 
DECLARE @PlaceIDofInterest   int  = 1,
       @StartDateOfInterest date = '20200101', 
       @EndDateOfInterest   date = '20200131';
   
;WITH date_range(d) AS -- the entire range of days we care about
(
 SELECT @StartDateOfInterest UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d) FROM date_range
        WHERE d < @EndDateOfInterest
),
islands AS -- grouped sets of days _not_ covered
(
 SELECT r.d, island = DATEADD(DAY, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.d) * -1, r.d) ,@PlaceIDofInterest as PlaceID
   FROM date_range AS r
   LEFT OUTER JOIN @t AS t
     ON  r.d >= t.StartDate 
     AND r.d <= t.EndDate
     AND t.PlaceID = @PlaceIDofInterest
   WHERE t.PlaceID IS NULL
)

SELECT MIN(d), MAX(d),PlaceID -- for each island, grab the start and end
 FROM islands 
 GROUP BY island ,PlaceID
 ORDER BY MIN(d);
```